# Code::blocks IDE and GitHub integration

Tags: git, github, ide, codeblocks

I am working on a university project with a friend, and we decided to host the thing in a GitHub repo. I am using the Code::Blocks IDE. It would be rather sensible if I could pull and push to my branch of the project on Git directly from within Code::Blocks, but I have not been able to figure out how.

Is there a plugin or some other tool that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GitHub Desktop, but it is not automated.

You can work in Code::Blocks and GitHub Desktop will show the files have changed (as long as you use the same directory/files for Code::Blocks and GitHub Desktop).

You will then have to manually push the files back to GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans has a Portable Version, put it on a USB and you will be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Use codeblock for your coding and use atom to push and pull your project code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).